# Configure SMTP for IIS 7.5 in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, iis-7, smtp

I was wondering if there's a way to get SMTP working for windows 7, IIS 7.5.  I checked all over,it said like there's no SMTP configuration for iiS7,windows 7.And followed 
[THESE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772058%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)  steps too.
Didn`t work out.
Please someone tell me if there is way to configure SMTP for IIS 7.5.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please define what you mean by "didn't work"? Did the commands fail? Did the mail just not get sent? A lot of times local anti-virus programs will block port 25 preventing smtp from working.

Comment: Sorry for that...When i send mails from my outlook account,it supposed to be in a folder in'C:\inetpub\mailroot\drop' . The mail is just not coming to the folder.So this means it`s failing right??

Comment: @Nate:You`ve any answers for my question?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to use this feature as a standard SMTP server that outlook can use.

The SMTP email feature you have installed is **NOT** a smtp server like was included with IIS6. Instead it is used to configure how email will be delivered when sent from your asp.net or other iis plugged in web applications.

That is why it allows you to specify the from email address on the configuration page.

---

[image: SMTP Screenshot]

---

For doing smtp testing I would recommend something line [freesmtp](http://www.softstack.com/freesmtp.html) which is a simple, single binary, smtp server you can use for testing outbound smtp traffic from any program.

Comment: :Thanks for replying. I have installed the setup of 'freesmtp' link, do I need to make changes as 'SMTP E-Mail' from iis manager(above)??

Comment: You shouldn't be doing anything with the smtp portion of iis unless you are developing or configuring a web application to send email.

Comment: But how mails will come to drop folder??I want outlook mails to come to drop folder.

Comment: How can I make my outlook mails to come to drop folder??For specific account in outlook.